# Ubuntu Server - Configuring BIND9 and Apache to serve domain and subdomains

Tags: bind, apache-2.4, ubuntu-14.04

First off, let me apologise for a perhaps vague question.

I need some pointers on how to configure the setup describe below. I'm not asking for finished configuration file, but I'm failing to piece this together.

**Setup**

- Several computers connected to a router.
- Server (Ubuntu Server LTS 14.04) connected to router.
- Router connected to internet.
- Company website hosted elsewhere - `example.com`
- Local websites hosted on local server - `git.example.com`, `issues.example.com`

**Currently**

I'm thinking that I can set router to use server as primary DNS. Server is running Bind9 and resolves subdomain (`git.example.com` and `issues.example.com`) to server's static IP. Apache servers content. Bind9 does not resolve `example.com`, so router uses secondary DNS for that (or Bind9 can redirect to another DNS server).

So far, I can configure the setup so that I can access `example.com/git` and `example.com/issues`, but then I can't access `example.com`.

So, my questions are: how do I configure Bind9 to resolve `git.example.com` but not `example.com` and how do I configure Apache to serve `git.example.com` differently (i.e. another document root?) from `issues.example.com`? And if, how are Bind9 and Apache related to each other?

Hope this makes sense, I recently started with this whole server-thing and only have very basic theoretical understanding of networking. :)

*Edit*: To be clear; `git.example.com` and `issues.example.com` does not need to be (or even should be) accessible from outside our network.

*Edit2*: Added picture.
[image: Intended setup]

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault and thank you for posting a question. Getting good answers requires the effort of [writing a good question](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3609/37681) and as it stands now yours is actually two different questions and missing what research and solutions you have already attempted. - Please improve your question or run the risk of leaving your problem unresolved and/or having your question closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, let's clear up a misconception.  This statement is not correct: "Bind9 does not resolve example.com, so router uses secondary DNS for that."  DNS resolvers do not go thru the list of configured DNS servers until it finds a response it likes.  They generally assume all the servers will respond correctly and stop after one server responds (positively or negatively).

Now to the actual problem at hand.  It appears that git.example.com and issues.example.com are not subdomains but actually server/host names. A subdomain might look something like: git.yourdepartment.example.com, with "yourdepartment.example.com" being the subdomain. If this the case (they are actually server names), then you would want the admin of the DNS server responsible for example.com to add those 2 A records for you.  Then on your DNS (Bind9) servers create a forwarding zone for example.com:

```
        zone "example.com" {
            type forward;
            allow-query {any; }; // modify as you see fit
            forwarders {
                    ip.of.dns.server1;
                    ip.of.dns.server2;
            };
        };
```

(Edit: Or just run a caching nameserver)

After this is done, you should be able to easily setup virtual hosts in Apache for each of the git.example.com and issues.example.com servers (There's no shortage of guides and tutorials for that).

Edit: The relationship between DNS and Apache?  The DNS takes the hostname from the URL and returns the IP address of a server (Apache in this case) capable of servicing the request. That's all. (OK, that's greatly oversimplified, but pretty accurate)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and clarifications! (And sorry for my late reply) If I have understood this correctly; I can not map `git.example.com` to our git repository locally on our network, I would have to contact the admin of the DNS server of `example.com` to set up the proper records? I have added a picture to the post to better illustrate.